# How to merge a generator with a JSON tree

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following python code that is to replace low-precision temperatures in a list of JSON trees, `ec2_tcs['zones']` with higher precision temps from a generator, `ec1_api.temperatures()`.

```
if CONF_HIGH_PRECISION:
    try:
        from evohomeclient import EvohomeClient as EvohomeClientVer1
        ec1_api = EvohomeClientVer1(client.username, client.password)

        for temp in ec1_api.temperatures(force_refresh=True):
            for zone in ec2_tcs['zones']:
                if str(temp['id']) == str(zone['zoneId']):
                    if zone['temperatureStatus']['isAvailable']:
                        zone['temperatureStatus']['temperature'] \
                            = temp['temp']
                    break

# TypeError: usually occurs in client library if problems with vendor's website
    except TypeError:
        _LOGGER.warning(
            "Failed to obtain higher-precision temperatures"
        )
```

The JSON data looks like this (an array of JSON data, 1 per 'zone'):

```
[
  {
    'zoneId': '3432521',
    'name': 'Main Room'
    'temperatureStatus': {'temperature': 21.5, 'isAvailable': True},
    'setpointStatus': {'targetHeatTemperature': 5.0, 'setpointMode': 'FollowSchedule'},
    'activeFaults': [],
  }, {
...
...
  }
]
```

and each result from the generator like this:

```
{'thermostat': 'EMEA_ZONE', 'id': 3432521, 'name': 'Main Room', 'temp': 21.55, 'setpoint': 5.0}
```

I know Python must have a better way of doing this, but I can't seem to make it fly.  Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

I could 'massage' the generator, but there are good reasons why the JSON tree's schema should remain unchanged.

The primary goal is to reduce a number of nested code blocks with a very fancy one-liner!